# Error:(8, 30) error: cannot find symbol class ActionBarActivity even when i have compiled com.android.support:support

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Here I have the  Error:(8, 30) error: cannot find symbol class ActionBarActivity:

[image: Here i have the Error:(8, 30) error: cannot find symbol class ActionBarActivity]

I'm receiving a strange error even after I've added `com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.2` to my gradle.

My gradle sync is successful but when I  try to run the app. I get this error.

Please Help!

This is My added libraries:

[image: This is My added libraries]

and my Gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "luck.materialdesign.tabsnavigator"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.2'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.15'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.1'
compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because **ActionBarActivity** has been removed starting from support library version 26.0.0-beta2. You can check it at
https://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/26.0.0-beta2/changes/alldiffs_index_removals.html

So, you must migrate your ActionBarActivity to **AppCompatActivity** and **Toolbar**.